# meteor 0.9 "list" shows "new versions of these packages are available" but "update" doesn't

Tags: meteor, package

```
$ meteor list
...
 * New versions of these packages are available! Run 'meteor update' to update.
$ meteor update
Figuring out the best package versions to use. This may take a moment.
This project is at the latest release which is compatible with your
current package constraints.
```

See the simplified version below:

[image]

It seems like there's a "conflict" between the `list` command which is saying there are updates available, and the `update` command which can not find any... how can this happen?

Comment: have you tried removing the packages and adding them back in?

Comment: Yup - I did that... but perhaps I didn't remove all of them...  I can try doing each.

but still, why the conflicting messages?

Comment: having a new version for an individual package is not the same as having a satisfying solution with all those packages upgraded. And remove `cmather:iron-router` and replace it with `iron:router`

Comment: My guess is you were using Meteorite and the migrate-app screwed up a bit, remove all packages and add then back and I think you'll be fine. make sure you add the right packages though (iron:router instead of cmather:iron-router and etc).

Comment: @ErezHochman I think you're exactly right...  2 problems, outlined below.

Answer (score 6):

The problem seemed to be the `mrt migrate-app` script, which was a convenient way to upgrade... but apparently left some cruft around.

### problems

1. some of the packages were guessed a bit wrong... with `cmather:iron-router` when it should be `iron:router` and more like that... (wish there was some way to filter/vote/identify "good" packages)
2. some of the packages were added with version suffixes like `@2.0.0` and those were holding up the update... so `list` says "there are updates available" but `update` doesn't get them...  **<-- answer**

### solution

remove all packages, update, add them all back, without the version suffix...
pretty easy to do now that they are all single lines in the `.meteor/packages` file:

```
sed -e 's/^[a-zA-Z0-9]/meteor remove &/' .meteor/packages | sed 's/\@[0-9\.]*//g' > packages-rm.sh
sed -e 's/ remove / add /' packages-rm.sh > packages-add.sh
bash packages-rm.sh
meteor list  # should be empty
meteor update
bash packages-add.sh
meteor list
```