# Could not resolve the specified constraints for this project: Error: conflict: blaze@1.0.0 vs 2.0.0

Tags: meteor

I tried to upgrade my meteor app from 0.8something to 0.9.1.1 and now

> Could not resolve the specified constraints for this project: Error:
>   conflict: blaze@1.0.0 vs 2.0.0

I'm not sure how to proceed. I try to run `meteor list` and `meteor remove` but no matter what meteor command I run I get this error.

The steps I did were

1. run `meteor update`

> updated to Meteor 0.9.1.1.

2. run `mrt migrate-app`

got some errors

```
 Error: The version 1.2.11 of package roles has not yet been migrated
 Error: The version 1.2.0 of package accounts-meld has not yet been
 migrated Error: The version 2.4.13 of package kadira has not yet been
 migrated Error: The version 0.4.8 of package analytics has not yet
 been migrated Error: The version 2.1.0.2 of package momentjs has not
 yet been migrated Error: The version 1.0.2 of package subs-manager has
 not yet been migrated

 If you want to continue, remove the package(s) from smart.json, run
 `mrt install`, and try again. After you have successfully migrated,
 you can add them back but note:   You will NOT receive further
 updates!. See https://hackpad.com/Migrating-Apps-UfPrM192vSQ for more
 information.
```

3. removed those packages from smart.json and ran mrt install. no errors
4. reran mrt migrate-app. This time no errors.

But now I can't do anything as I always get the error

```
 meteor list

Figuring out the best package versions to use. This may take a moment.
Refreshing package metadata. This may take a moment.
Could not resolve the specified constraints for this project:
Error: conflict: blaze@1.0.0 vs 2.0.0
```

Please help troubleshoot. Thanks.

Comment: Try removing the `.meteor/vesions` file as well and start adding your packages from scratch with `meteor add`. Remember about correct prefixes.

Comment: i just tried. no luck. even after deleting the versions file and doing meteor add X:y results in the error message

Comment: I ended up deleting the .meteor/packages file, re-adding it, then manually adding all the packages. I am not sure if that was what I was supposed to do but it seems to have worked.

Comment: So frustrating... the last two meteor updates for me recently were chalk full of breaking changes... anyways, big hassle but going through and prepending most app.use(*) calls with the right user: prefix per package fixed my issue. Also, `mrt migrate-package...`

Comment: @landland suggestion worked for me with 0.9.4 to overcome unknown packages and constraints

Answer (score 3):

as I figured out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25735863/meteor-0-9-list-shows-new-versions-of-these-packages-are-available-but-upda/25746429#25746429), perhaps you should try out:

remove all packages, update, add them all back, without the version suffix... pretty easy to do now that they are all single lines in the .meteor/packages file:

```
sed -e 's/^[a-zA-Z0-9]/meteor remove &/' .meteor/packages | sed 's/\@[0-9\.]*//g' > packages-rm.sh
sed -e 's/ remove / add /' packages-rm.sh > packages-add.sh
bash packages-rm.sh
meteor list  # should be empty
meteor update
bash packages-add.sh
meteor list
```